# From DecisionTable to map

Tags: testing, automated-tests, drools, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I would like to create a dynamic data structure from a DecisionTable or similar.

For what I can tell only staticly typed datastructure is possible as follows:

wiki code:

```
|should I buy milk|
|cash in wallet|credit card|broke?|
|0             |0          |yes   |
```

The columns must map to the fixture by setter: setCashInWallet(int cash) and setCreditcard(int credit).

What i like to do is something more flexible where each column is populated to a list:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> decisionTable = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();    
Map<String, Object> row = new  HashMap<String, Object>();
```

In the setup of the test I specify the target object, ex: com.domain.MoneyIHave.
In the fixture I will convert the data structure via reflection to instances of this.

The api for adding facts (data structure) to the drools session is loose coupled.

```
StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
for( Object fact : facts ) { //<----- loose baby!
    ksession.insert( fact );
}
ksession.fireAllRules();
ksession.dispose();
```

If this is possible I can create a couple fixtures that is immune to data structure changes. These fixtures could handle almost all scenarios.

But I can´t find any example of this.

Tnx in avance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at table tables?

http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM.TableTable

Comment: Please explain your thought more thorough.

Comment: For what I can see that table does not call a fixture. So that is of no use.